# Spring batch Read flat file having only one huge line with fixed length records

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to process a flat file in spring batch. this file has only ONE line which is huge and has multiple records. each record is fixed length , say 160 chars . and again each record in turn has fixed length fields.

moreover there is also parent - child relationship between records.

i cant use default bufferedreader since it looks for new line char. has somebody encountered this kind of requirement . looks like i need to make spring batch flat file item reader to treat 'length' as a line instead of new line and also combine RecordSeparatorPolicy for parent-child relationship.

any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: BufferedReader has two `read()` methods you could use instead of `readLine()` to read character by character or a range of characters.  Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You have the right idea.  Have you tried something that isn’t working or are you looking to validate your idea before writing the code?

Comment: Thanks @JoeChiavaroli , i will try that.

Comment: I am looking to validate the idea @MichaelMinella ,  and also if there is a better way to achieve this. thank you